# How to make videos show thumbnail in ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: thumbnails

I have ubuntu 13.04 and many of my videos do not show thumbnails whereas some do, they are all Mp4 formats including the ones that do show thumbnails.

Is there a way to make all videos show thumbnails?

The ones that do show them were on my old operating system when i had windows 7 so after movinng them from pc to external hardrive to pc (with new os, ubuntu 13.04) the thumbnail remained, whereas new videos do not show the thumbnail.

Comment: Is it the same files all the time. I had a similar problem, but most of the time it was just taking the thumbnails time to load.

Comment: yer its the same files, only 4 specific videos show the thumbnail every time and the rest don't show them ever, no matter how long the folder is open for.

Answer (score 8):

First install:

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg ffmpegthumbnailer gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg
```

then

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/thumbnailers/totem.thumbnailer
```

replace contents with following:

```
[Thumbnailer Entry]
TryExec=ffmpegthumbnailer
Exec=ffmpegthumbnailer -s %s -i %i -o %o -c png -f -t 10
MimeType=application/mxf;application/ogg;application/ram;application/sdp;application/vnd.ms-wpl;application/vnd.rn-realmedia;application/x-extension-m4a;application/x-extension-mp4;application/x-flash-video;application/x-matroska;application/x-netshow-channel;application/x-ogg;application/x-quicktimeplayer;application/x-shorten;image/vnd.rn-realpix;image/x-pict;misc/ultravox;text/x-google-video-pointer;video/3gpp;video/dv;video/fli;video/flv;video/mp2t;video/mp4;video/mp4v-es;video/mpeg;video/msvideo;video/ogg;video/quicktime;video/vivo;video/vnd.divx;video/vnd.rn-realvideo;video/vnd.vivo;video/webm;video/x-anim;video/x-avi;video/x-flc;video/x-fli;video/x-flic;video/x-flv;video/x-m4v;video/x-matroska;video/x-mpeg;video/x-ms-asf;video/x-ms-asx;video/x-msvideo;video/x-ms-wm;video/x-ms-wmv;video/x-ms-wmx;video/x-ms-wvx;video/x-nsv;video/x-ogm+ogg;video/x-theora+ogg;video/x-totem-stream;audio/x-pn-realaudio;audio/3gpp;audio/ac3;audio/AMR;audio/AMR-WB;audio/basic;audio/midi;audio/mp2;audio/mp4;audio/mpeg;audio/ogg;audio/prs.sid;audio/vnd.rn-realaudio;audio/x-aiff;audio/x-ape;audio/x-flac;audio/x-gsm;audio/x-it;audio/x-m4a;audio/x-matroska;audio/x-mod;audio/x-mp3;audio/x-mpeg;audio/x-ms-asf;audio/x-ms-asx;audio/x-ms-wax;audio/x-ms-wma;audio/x-musepack;audio/x-pn-aiff;audio/x-pn-au;audio/x-pn-wav;audio/x-pn-windows-acm;audio/x-realaudio;audio/x-real-audio;audio/x-sbc;audio/x-speex;audio/x-tta;audio/x-wav;audio/x-wavpack;audio/x-vorbis;audio/x-vorbis+ogg;audio/x-xm;application/x-flac;
```

Comment: This worked for me perfectly, thank you very much nightcrawler!

Answer (score 1):

1. Install ffmpegthumbnailer
2. Delete the fail folder inside .thumbnails in home directory.
3. Change the permissions of folder ".cache/thumbnails" in home directory by following command:

   ```
   sudo chmod 777 -R .cache/thumbnails
   ```
4. Delete the files inside folder .cache/thumbnails/fail
5. Kill nautilus and restart nautilus
6. Visit the video folder :)

Comment: This did not generate thumbnails for my mp4 video files.

Comment: Loaded my thumbnails without changing folder permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  Install libxine1-ffmpeg, it might be needed for some thumbnails.  To install, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install libxine1-ffmpeg
```

Comment: Didn't work, any other ideas? I have also tried Files > Preferences and changing the show thumbnails to "Always" but still dont work.

Answer (score -1):

From: [Gnome 3 not displaying thumbnails?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164055/gnome-3-not-displaying-thumbnails/382596#382596)

Had the same problem with Ubuntu 13.10 - Gnome3. 
Solved it deleting whole folder thumbnails in /.cache and remaking it.

1) Disable preview in nautilus by opening home folder, Edit-> Preferences-> Preview.

2) `sudo rm ~/.cache/thumbnails`

3) Empty trash can

4) `sudo mkdir ~/.cache/thumbnails`

5) Reboot

6) Enable preview, again home folder, Edit-> Preferences-> Preview.

Done.

Worked for me.

k.